# Real player plugin for Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, google-chrome, debian, realplayer

What is the best way to install a plugin capable of playing real videos for Debian Linux?

In particular I want this web page to run correctly under Iceweasel and Chrome:
http://bleau.info/sabots/781-1267.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enjoy](http://www.real.com/realplayer/linux).